# JQuery Ajax loop delay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to make a delay in my ajax data so the loop become a little bit slower !
and here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#button').click(function(){

 $('#hide').show();
 var data = $('#textarea').val();

 var arrayOfLines = data.split("\n"); 

 var track = JSON.stringify(arrayOfLines);
 var item = "";

 var lines = $('#textarea').val().split('\n');
```

here is the loop

```
 for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
     item = lines[i];
            $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
                url: 'cookie.php',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: 'data=' + item+'&cookie='+track,
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#results').append(msg);

                }

                });
 }

});
```

Comment: where is the code `to make a delay` ? I see nothing that would result in any sort of delay. Did you forget to write it?

Comment: Don't send AJAX requests in a loop (delayed or otherwise). Make a single request with *all* the data in it and separate it out on the server. Your current pattern will just DDOS your own server.

Comment: You can send all data at once, in order not to have to control the traffic

Comment: i tried to do that but the php loop doesn't print what is finished it keep loading until the foreach is done and then print the result at once ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using recursion, you could put in a function `sendToServer` and pass through the array `lines`, starting index 0. The function will run from 0 to lines.length. This way you won't DDOS your server :)

If you really need some kind of arbitrary delay, you can include a timeout on the `sendToServer` function call - in the example it is set to 5 seconds.

```
 var sendToServer = function(lines, index){
   if (index > lines.length) return; // guard condition
   item = lines[index];
   if (item.trim().length != 0){
     $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'cookie.php',
       dataType: 'html',
       data: 'data=' + item+'&cookie='+track,
       success: function(msg){
         $('#results').append(msg);             
         setTimeout(
           function () { sendToServer(lines, index+1); }, 
           5000 // delay in ms
         );             
       }
     });
   }
   else { sendToServer(lines, index+1); }
};

sendToServer(lines, 0);
```

Comment: thx this worked for me ! :) can u please tell me how to prevent empty values like " " or empty line to be send in the request

Comment: Thx Man this worked too ..... i really appreciate your help .. well done

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

It's always a good idea to Google around and figure out the problem yourself though, I think that's why many people downvoted your question, besides the questionable technique of sending data to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Don't send request to server in for loop. It can take down the server. Instead of what you did , you can do this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
     item = lines[i];
}  

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
        url: 'cookie.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: 'data=' + item+'&cookie='+track,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#results').append(msg);

        }

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
 var timeDelay = 5000;       
    setTimeout(Function, timeDelay);
```

Comment: move your loop in a function 'foo' and use it in place of 'Function'